# Fitnesse - Remote debug error

Tags: fitnesse

I'm trying to enable remote-debugging with fitnesse. Getting below error.

> Could not complete testing: java.lang.Exception: FitClient: external
>   process terminated before a connection could be established.

To start fitnesse in debug-mode, i'm adding below startup command

```
set DEBUG_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=9000

java -jar %DEBUG_OPTS% fitnesse-standalone.jar -p 81
```

And with this, able to connect to the Fitness process, but enabling Tools->Remote Debug from Fitnesse GUI gives above error. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FitNesse is starting the System under test in a separate process by default. You can execute the test suite with debugging enabled, e.g. "MySuite?suite&debug".

Make sure all required libraries are on your class path (the one you use to start FitNesse "java -cp jar1.jar:classes:fitnesse-standalone.jar fitnesseMain.FitNesseMain -p 81"), since your application will be started inside the FitNesse process.